# When using local python modules and pip, how to avoid creating a new version with every edit?

Tags: python, pip

I'm sure this has been answered elsewhere, but I must not know the right keywords to find the answer...

I'm working on a site that requires several different components deployed on different servers but relying on some shared functions. I've implemented this by putting the shared functions into a pip module in its own git repo that I can put into the requirements.txt file of each project.

This is pretty standard stuff - more or less detailed here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip

My question is now that I have this working to deploy code into production, how do I set up my dev environment in such a way that I can make edits to the code in the shared module without having to do all of the following?
1. Commit changes
2. increment the version in setup.py in shared library
3. Increment in requirements.txt
4. pip install -r requirements.txt

That's a lot of steps to do all over again if I make one typo.

Answer (score 0):

On a similar note, I used jenkins with git hook and a simple(4 or 5 lines maybe that would install/upgrade requirements.txt, restart webserver and little more stuff) bash script. When I commit changes, jenkins would run my bash script, then voila. Almost instant upgrade.

But note that, this is hack-ish. Jenkins is a continuous integration tool focusing building and testing, and there are probably better and simpler tools in this case, hint: Continuous Integration.